# How to run .ipa from Xcode on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, ipa

I can use Xcode to export my app to Mac disk end with .ipa, but I don't know how to install .ipa file on Mac, so I can run the app.

below is the a screenshot how the files look like:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode, choose Window->Devices and Simulators. The Devices and Simulators window comes up. Select the Devices tab. With the device you wish to install selected on the left-hand side of the window, drag the .ipa file onto the right-hand side under "Installed Apps".

Comment: I don't want to install on a Simulator, I want it to run on Mac

Answer (score 2):

An .ipa file contains an iOS app. You can't install and run an iOS app directly on a Mac.

If you want to make a Mac version of an iPad app, select the Mac device target for your app target and use the Catalyst framework.

[image]